# How can I get 10 selected ID`s from objectIDs?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to extract 10 ids from and object "objectIDs" and put them into an array "idArr". "objectIDs" is an object I get when fetching data (code bellow). The problem is that "objectIDs" is an array? objectIDs[ 0:[array of id`s which I want to extract] 1:[another array of ids] 2:[...] .... ] I want to pass 10 of the 0th index ids from objectIDs but don`t seem to be able to as the "idArr" I pass them to looks like [0:ID,1:id,...,10:ID]. And I can`t seem to make use of that array. Would like to find a way to pass the ids from "objectIDs" to "objArr" in the format [ID,ID,ID...,ID]. Is that possible?

```js
let idArr = [];

function getObjectIds() {
  fetch("https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/search?hasImages=true&q=early renaissance")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        idArr.unshift(data.objectIDs);
      }
    })
}

getObjectIds();
console.log(idArr);
```

Sample data from the link:

```
{"total":1613,"objectIDs":[199003,22369,207034,208555,436918,390196,387111,480645,460738,459129,206912,437203,21126,10705,12569,438688,207010,75586,386903,363020,437245,468639,436666,468166,696866,386797,386933,386934,35842,23144,436989,196207,196205,196206,436988,195186,461131,460494,459246,25396,193617,21974,206757,462776,505681,437912,813840,437372,436051,436101,201862,459088,437059,193625,193626,186124,505501,460490,468716,467746,204722,472562,503517,186170,471933,471934,337061,197033,195447,437593,447570,468165,201398,202389,202388,459072,473871,676458,428525,236192,460611,23229,210185,191486,460498,25562,25486,25528,25444,207394,458978,467760,435728,201910,445297,5223,195190,468431,203921,201802,460832,460645,207257,474336,435595,202970,201375,192912,437007,195054,197757,471931,471938,471936,471935,471937]}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) creates a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) of your original array, with the parameters standing for start index and end index.

```js
const data = {"total":1613,"objectIDs":[199003,22369,207034,208555,436918,390196,387111,480645,460738,459129,206912,437203,21126,10705,12569,438688,207010,75586,386903,363020,437245,468639,436666,468166,696866,386797,386933,386934,35842,23144,436989,196207,196205,196206,436988,195186,461131,460494,459246,25396,193617,21974,206757,462776,505681,437912,813840,437372,436051,436101,201862,459088,437059,193625,193626,186124,505501,460490,468716,467746,204722,472562,503517,186170,471933,471934,337061,197033,195447,437593,447570,468165,201398,202389,202388,459072,473871,676458,428525,236192,460611,23229,210185,191486,460498,25562,25486,25528,25444,207394,458978,467760,435728,201910,445297,5223,195190,468431,203921,201802,460832,460645,207257,474336,435595,202970,201375,192912,437007,195054,197757,471931,471938,471936,471935,471937]};

const first10 = data.objectIDs.slice(0, 10);

console.log(first10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood problem correctly:
input: [[1,7,5...8], [],..... []]
output: [1,7,5...8]

Try below code:

```
 function getObjectIds(){
   ....
   const idArr = objectIDs[0];
   return idArr;
}
```

Comment: So it seems as I tweaked the code, data.objectIDs[i] returns a number which is correct. But when I try to push IDs idArr.push(data.objectIDs[i]) to fill the idArr with "i" number of IDs from data.objectIDs, idArr[i] returns undefined?

Comment: As javascript is asynchronous your `console.log()` runs before `.then()`

Comment: I noticed that if "idArr" is declared inside the fetch function the numbers are pushed properly and can be logged but is there a way to use "idArr" outside the fetch if it is defined inside the fetch function? I apollogise for the lack of knowledge on the matter.

Comment: There are 2 options:
1. Move `console.log()` inside `.then()` and after populating `idArr`

2. Or use async await

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will try both ways and see which suits me better. I`m still learning to use fetch and asynchronous functions so that explanation really helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let idArr = [];

function getObjectIds() {
  fetch("https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/search?hasImages=true&q=early renaissance")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("real dta", data);
        idArr = data.objectIDs.slice(0, 10);
      console.log("id arr", idArr);
    });
}

getObjectIds();
```